# Share function with React Router to all routs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to unmount Navbar component from Mein component so that event listeners are also gone.
One the example below (App.js), it works but then I don't know how to share toShowNav function to change showNav value?

```
 toShowNav(value) {
   this.setState({ showNav: value });
 }

<Router history={this.history}>
  <Switch>
      {
        this.state.showNav && <NavBar />
      }
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}  />
      <Route exact path="/Users" component={Usera} />
      <Route exact path="/Main" component={Main} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`render`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) prop to pass additional props to your components:

```
toShowNav(value) {
  this.setState({ showNav: value });
}

<Router history={this.history}>
  <Switch>
    { this.state.showNav && <NavBar /> }
    <Route exact path="/" render={ props => 
      <Home {...props} toShowNav={this.toShowNav} /> }  
    />
    <Route exact path="/Users" render={ props =>
      <Users {...props} toShowNav={this.toShowNav} /> }
    />
    <Route exact path="/Main" render={ props =>
      <Main {...props} toShowNav={this.toShowNav} /> }
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Thank you for a reply, this will help me for sure. Later I will have more than 20 Routes, is there a way to share function automatically between them, without using render on every Route?

Comment: You can use a Higher Order Component and wrap each individual component or create a stand alone file that exports the function and you can import that into each component.